# What is a "Production" in plain English?

Tags: parsing, grammar

I can read on Wikipedia the formal definition of a [Production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_%28computer_science%29), however when you start reading that article, it makes an assumption about prior knowledge.

Wikipedia defines it as follows:

> A production or production rule in computer science is a rewrite rule specifying a symbol substitution that can be recursively performed to generate new symbol sequences.

This assumes that I know and understand what a *rewrite rule* is.  I don't, and if I click the link, I get into another fairly technical explanation.

Can someone explain to me in plain English what a Production actually is?

*Note*: I have made many attempts to understand this, but I don't think I've succeeded.  From what I can tell it rewrites the given string in terms of grammar rules.  Not sure if I'm correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain what a production is I'd like to introduce a bit of context first.

The dragon book states that a context free grammar has 4 components:

- a set of terminal symbols (tokens)
- a set of non-terminal symbols (syntactic variables)
- a set of productions of the form: non-term --> sequence of terminals and non-terminals
- a non-terminal symbol designated as the start symbol

It is also said that parsing is the problem of taking a string of terminals (the source code) and figuring out what are the steps required to derive this string of terminals from the start symbol of the grammar.

Now that this has been said, a production is essentially a possible (intermediate) step. I say possible because some symbols can derive into different sequences.

For example, let's make a simple grammar to represent an arbitrarily long sequences of a's ending with a b. The 4 components of this grammar would be:

- Terminals: a, b
- Non-terminals: S, X
- Rules: S --> X, X --> aX, X --> ab
- Start symbol: S

From the description I gave above "aaaab" should be derivable from this grammar. Let's see if that holds up. We start from, the start symbol, and then apply productions until a) we get the final sequence, b) we exhaust all possibilities without succeeding (meaning the sequence is not "grammatically correct").

```
S
X (after applying S --> X)
aX (after applying X --> aX)
aaX (after applying X --> aX)
aaaX (after applying X --> aX)
aaaab (after applying X --> ab)
```

And we're done, we got the original sequence. So as you can see we re-wrote the non-terminal symbols by applying rules (one of them we applied recursively) which transformed the sequence into a new sequence of symbols at every step and we did so until we had the final sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A rewrite rule is a method of replacing subterms of a formula with other terms. In their most basic form, they consist of a set of objects, plus relations on how to transform those objects.

An example of a rewrite rule could look like:

```
A → B
```

Now as for what this actually does! You are right on your note, take for example a list of things (and 2 rewrite rules):

```
X, Y, Z
X → Y
Y → Z
```

Which would result in:

```
Z, Z, Z
```

A production rule is a rewrite rule because it is a method of replacing subterms of a formula (probably a string in your case). A production rule could look like:

```
X, Y, Z
X → aX
```

By using the rule in such a way it becomes possible to apply recursion (create new sequences) as it will keep replacing itself:

```
aX, Y, Z
aaX, Y, Z
aaaX, Y, Z
```

As for the question you are asking, you could say: "A production rule is a replacement rule for formulas that uses recursion to create new sequences".